# Create an EBS based EC2 AMI from Ubuntu server with some tools installed

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04, amazon-ebs, amazon-web-services, linux

1. Download Ubuntu Server (last LTS version, 10.04)

   2. Install it under VirtualStudio, or any other VM.
   3. Install some useful stuff for GIS developers, like build essentials, PostgreSQL, PostGIS and GDAL
   4. Upload this image as AMI, to allow other developers to use it.

I'm reading this thread [How to create EBS based EC2 AMI from scratch?](https://serverfault.com/questions/91006/how-to-create-ebs-based-ec2-ami-from-scratch) and the Ubuntu EC2 Starter guide (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide). Should I check any other documentation? Apart from EC2 Starters guide.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should check [alestic.com](http://alestic.com/)! You'll find lots of useful Articles about ec2, ubuntu-amis, etc. and perhaps you will find out, that it is better to use the ready-to-go ubuntu-10.04-ebs-ami from Alestic than to do it yourself! I can absolutely recommend the Alestic AMIs - we have many of them in production.

Comment: Hi heiko, thanks for you response. I'll check the AMIs from alestic. Only a quick question? May I use one of that AMIs, modify it and the upload to Amazon with the modifications?

Thanks again